# Layout parameter layout_weight ignored unless both layout_width and layout_height are also specified on <include> tag

Tags: java, android

I get this message as an error and am not able to run the app.

```
    <include 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/button_row"/>
<include 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/button_row"/>
<include 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/button_row"/>    
 <include 

    layout="@layout/button_row"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

android:layout_weight="1" this lines cause errors. However, they make the layout file look as a need (in the screenshot)[image]

Here is what in the include tag

```
   <style name="RemoteButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width"> 0dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_height"> match_parent </item>`
```

How can I make it look like I need without having errors? Thank you

Comment: Hey, just a question, but shouldnt your android:layout_weight="1", be placed inside your include tag style since you want it all to be weight 1?

Comment: @cokeby190 Yes it should, but  in this particular case I need it to be outside the include tag

Answer (score 0):

Change `styles.xml` to this
It will work the same

```
<style name="RemoteButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width"> 0dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_height"> match_parent </item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
<style>
```